# Add (end-)cards to a Youtube video using the Youtube Data API V3

Tags: go, youtube

is it currently possible to add cards and endcards to a youtube video using the Youtube Data API V3?

I know it wasn't able to add the oldschool annotations to a video using an API, a developer answered that there won't be any option to do so and those are deprecated now anyways.

There are the invideoPromotion(also deprecated according to the API documentation) features present in the API, but due to the lack of information I am not entirely sure what I can achieve with that.
(https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource)

Do I have to update a channel just so I can add some annotations to one single video?

Is it even possible to add proper annotations to a video or can i only add the watermark?

I've searched for hours on end, without finding a definitive answer or an example of how I am supposed to add annotations to a video.

I use a Go-server to upload Videos and thumbnails for my clients and would love a feature where they don't have to insert the annotations by hand after the video is uploaded.